# Can't run vscode debugger for Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to run debugger for java in vscode but nothing is happening it just flickers and just run the code.
Here is my json file and i have tried several configurations but nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no breakpoint set, the extension **debugger for java** will indeed flickers and run the code.

After [creating a launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations), adding a breakpoint before the code you want to debug, then clicking Debug, debug toolbar will appear on the top of the editor. You may continue, step over or stop the debug session. For your reference:
[image]

Detailed information please view [Debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the debugger first:

- Go to the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X)
- Filter the extensions list by typing "java"
- Select "Debugger for Java"

In addition I would advise you to use Intellij instead. VSCode is a nice tool but I guess for java you can have better.

Comment: I have already installed the java extension pack which already has a java debugger in it but still it isn't working and thanks for suggesting IntelliJ but im using vscode for lite work not working on any project.

Comment: Intellij has a free community edition, I use it all the time for my projects.